# Wordpress get post via sql query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I grabbed the code that wordpress uses to display the default calendar and it gets the dates like this:

```
if ( $day == current_time( 'j' ) &&
    $thismonth == current_time( 'm' ) &&
    $thisyear == current_time( 'Y' ) ) {
}
```

Using those values (day, month and year), how can I write a mysql query that pulls the post created on that specific date?

I tried to have [this link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query) as reference but my sql skills are close to none.

EDITED:

My table name is "wp_posts" and the date column is named as post_date.

Accosrding to the answer here I did the following:

```
$date = new DateTime($thisyear."-".$thismonth."-".$day);

$date->setTime($hours, $minutes, $seconds);

$date_format = $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$request = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_date = ".$date_format);

$result = $request->fetch();
```

but when I var_mp $result, nothing happens

```
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Do you want to write an SQL query or use an internal wordpress function?

Comment: What about https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/310394/how-to-get-posts-on-a-specific-date-wp-query?

Answer (score 0):

If the field of your database is type of  "DATE" you can (with PDO):

```
$date = new DateTime($thisyear."-".$thismonth."-".$day); //__Create my object date

$date_format = $date->format("Y-m-d"); //__Date formatting

$request = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE date_article = ".$date_format); //__Create my SQL query

$result = $request->fetch() //__Or 'fetchAll' if many result could be possible
```

---

### EDIT

---

If the field of your database is type of  "DATETIME" you can (with PDO):

```
$date = new DateTime($thisyear."-".$thismonth."-".$day); //__Create my object date

$date->setTime($hours, $minutes, $seconds);

$date_format = $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"); //__Date formatting

$request = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE date_article = ".$date_format); //__Create my SQL query

$result = $request->fetch() //__Or 'fetchAll' if many result could be possible
```

`$result` will contain your array with your article(s).

Comment: The filed in my table is of type datetime. Does it make a difference?

Comment: does not work, but I edited my question hoping that it helps

Comment: You have maybe no data  that match ?

Comment: I just realiszed that it's potentially a problem in the data. Because when I dump date_format, I get the year,month and day. However, the hours are  returned as 0's, which means that it wont find a match.
So, is there a way to fire the query and include only the year,month and day?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't comment on the above answer yet. So I'm going to post my comment as an answer.

I believe noting is being returned because your query doesn't match any value.

First

> Dump `$date_format` and see the output.

Secondly

> Compare the output you get with the values in `post_date`

Lastly

> Edit the build up of `$date_format` to match the values in `post_date` accordingly.